# Convergence of series of elements in a quasi-local algebra

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, operators, hilbert-space, mathematical-physics

I am studying the quasi-local algebra on Bratteli and Robinson *Operator Algebras and Quantum Statistical Mechanics*, but there is one thing that is not clear to me at the moment. Let's say that the quasi-local algebra is the norm-closure of $\mathcal{A} = \cup_{n=1}^{+\infty} \mathcal{A}_n $ where the set of $\mathcal{A}_n$ is an increasing net of C*-algebras. Let's consider the elements $O_n \in \mathcal{A}_n$, and let's consider the series of $\hat{O} = \sum_n^{N} O_n$. I would like to know if the convergence (either in norm or strongly or weakly) of the limit $N \to +\infty$ of $\hat{O}$ is guaranteed by the structure of the quasi-local algebra, or if it is not so obvious and that is something that has to be checked every time.

Comment: Sequences can converge or diverge, it entirely depends on the sequence. By the definition of norm-closure, limits of converging sequences are all contained in $\mathcal{A}$, that is, if your sequence of $O_n$ converges, then by definition $O \in \mathcal{A}$.

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov thank you for your comment! I was afraid it wasn't so simple. Is it possible that a sequence isn't converging in norm but it is converging weakly?

Comment: If a sequence converges weakly but doesn't converge in the norm topology, the limit may not exist in $\mathcal{A}$ (in case you define it as a norm-closure).